# SKAction moveTo goes up when should go down

Tags: ios, coordinates, sprite-kit

I was following the SpriteKit tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/49625/sprite-kit-tutorial-space-shooter) to create a simple sprite kit shooter, where you make a space ship that shoots lasers at asteroids.

I want to make the lasers (each laser is an SKSpriteNode) move to the point where I click. I am getting the touch correctly within the method `touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`. However when I setup an `SKAction` on the SKSpriteNode, it moves in the y direction OPPOSITE of where I click. Ie image the window has width (x) 500 and height (y) 400. When I touch the screen at the coordinate (300, 100), the lazer appears to move to the coordinate (300, 300).

I've verified that the coordinates in `touchLocation` are correct.

FYI I have only used the iPhone simulator for this - but that shouldn't matter, should it?

Relevant code snippet:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    SKSpriteNode *shipLaser = [_shipLasers objectAtIndex:_nextShipLaser];

    shipLaser.position = CGPointMake(_ship.position.x+shipLaser.size.width,_ship.position.y+0);
    shipLaser.hidden = NO;
    [shipLaser removeAllActions];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    SKAction *laserMoveAction = [SKAction moveTo:touchLocation duration:0.5];
    SKAction *laserDoneAction = [SKAction runBlock:(dispatch_block_t)^() {
        shipLaser.hidden = YES;
    }];

    SKAction *moveLaserActionWithDone = [SKAction sequence:@[laserMoveAction,laserDoneAction]];
    [shipLaser runAction:moveLaserActionWithDone withKey:@"laserFired"];
}
```

EDIT: I wonder if it might have to do with the fact that SprikeKit's coordinate system originates from the bottom left, while UIKit originates from the top left??

Comment: why `_ship.position.y+0`? Also, what is `shipLaser`'s parent ?

Comment: The `+0` is not important, it's a result of copy & pasting code from the tutorial. The parent of `shipLaser` is the view controller - within init method I call `[self addChild:shipLaser]` on each object in the `_shipLasers` array

Comment: You aren't adding the laser to to SKScene ?

Comment: Sorry I misspoke - The parent of `shipLaser` is `MyScene`, which extends `SKScene`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the touchLocation in the SKScene, not the UIView.

change :

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
```

to :

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that does the trick! :) This is the correct answer to my problem, but I'll leave my previous solution below as an explanation of why you need the touch's location in the SKScene, not the view.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that SprikeKit's coordinate system originates from the bottom left, unlike UIKit's coordinate system which originates in the top right. So the coordinates for the touch event were in the UIkit's coord system, and the SKNode was moving in SpriteKit's system. Once I understood this difference it was pretty easy to fix.

Comment: I would suggest you just use the SKScene coordinate system. What is your reason for not ?

Comment: I was unaware of that method until you suggested it, your solution is the correct one.

Comment: I would be surprised if the tutorial you are using used `locationInView`. Was just curious why you would choose to do so. Are you accustomed to working with UIKit ?

Comment: Yes, I am MUCH more accustomed to working with UIKit. The functionality I'm trying to implement with the laser moving towards the touch (and now have working!) was not in the tutorial. So there wasn't any guidance there